# Indentation Between Parentheses/Brackets/etc

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to have VSCode automatically indent items when I hit enter within the parenthesis to the start of the parenthesis like so below (similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383967/is-there-any-way-for-vs-code-to-indent-to-an-open-bracket)). This works well in Jupyter, but I can't find the same solution in VSCode and could not find a solution online. Does someone know how to achieve this may be through presets in VSCode? Thanks in advance.

**Current:**

```
dict = {
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2,
    "Three": 3
}
```

**Desired:**

```
dict = {"One": 1,
        "Two": 2,
        "Three": 3}
```

**EDIT**
@Shradha Although similar-sounding to what I'm looking for, your suggestion does not address the code in the manner I'm looking. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change indentation in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174207/how-to-change-indentation-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about presets but there is an extension that does just that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LAK132.indent-to-bracket